# Invalid parameter "robot_namespace" when running Husky Robot

Tags: gazebo, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone.

I want to run Husky Robot (http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/Husky) in my Gazebo simulator. Current version for Husky in ROS is still in Indigo, and Kinetic version is still not released yet. So I cloned Husky code from https://github.com/husky/husky into src folder in my new catkin workspace, compiled it using catkin_make, and run one of the launch file there :

```
roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_empty_world.launch
```

Then I met this errors:

```
Invalid parameter "robot_namespace"
XacroException('Invalid parameter "robot_namespace"',)
when instantiating macro: sick_lms1xx (/opt/ros/kinetic/share/lms1xx/urdf/sick_lms1xx.urdf.xacro)
in file: /home/myuserame/myworkspace/src/husky/husky_description/urdf/husky.urdf.xacro
while processing /home/myuserame/myworkspace/src/husky/husky_gazebo/launch/spawn_husky.launch:
while processing /home/myuserame/myworkspace/src/husky/husky_description/launch/description.launch:
Invalid < param > tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/xacro/xacro '/home/myuserame/myworkspace/src/husky/husky_description/urdf/husky.urdf.xacro'     --inorder     robot_namespace:=/     laser_enabled:=true     kinect_enabled:=false     urdf_extras:=     ] returned with code [2]. 

Param xml is < param command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find husky_description)/urdf/husky.urdf.xacro'     --inorder     robot_namespace:=$(arg robot_namespace)     laser_enabled:=$(arg laser_enabled)     kinect_enabled:=$(arg kinect_enabled)     urdf_extras:=$(arg urdf_extras)     " name="robot_description"/ >
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Am I missing something?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260838/invalid-parameter-%22robot_namespace%22-when-running-husky-robot/) by [nobinov](https://answers.ros.org/users/30226/nobinov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2017-05-02

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abrzozowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/28240/abrzozowski/) on 2017-05-10**:
I'm getting simillar error:

```
<:[2]~/catkin-ws$ /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/xacro/xacro '/home/adrian/catkin-ws/src/husky/husky_description/urdf/husky.urdf.xacro'     --inorder     robot_namespace:=/     laser_enabled:=true     kinect_enabled:=false     urdf_extras:=
```

**Comment by [abrzozowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/28240/abrzozowski/) on 2017-05-10**:
XacroException('Invalid parameter "robot_namespace"',)
when instantiating macro: sick_lms1xx (/opt/ros/kinetic/share/lms1xx/urdf/sick_lms1xx.urdf.xacro)
in file: /home/adrian/catkin-ws/src/husky/husky_description/urdf/husky.urdf.xacro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved ! Sorry for my late confirmation

As i issued on their Github (https://github.com/husky/husky), they current version of LMS1xx on repo is not updated yet and not supported the newest version of Husky. Then just like abrzozowski said, it needs to use newest version of LMS1xx from source at https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/LMS1xx

Further details please look at https://github.com/husky/husky/issues/49

---

Originally posted by [nobinov](https://answers.ros.org/users/30226/nobinov/) with karma: 66 on 2017-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1